# print data to different terminal IAR

Tags: c, terminal, embedded, msp430, iar

I am working on a project which contains acquisition of ECG data with the ADS1293EVM. MSP430F5529 is part of this board as well. For the communication between analog part of the board and microcontroller, I am using SPI and there is also FET Debugger from TI to program the microcontroller. Now I am printing data using printf to a terminal I/O which is part of the IAR software.

However, I would like to print ECG data to the terminal app in PC or to LabView, not in Terminal I/O in IAR software. The board is connected to the PC by USB so there is UART port in device manager. Is there any possibility?

Comment: What exactly is "terminal I/O" if not the UART port? What's stopping you from using a terminal? Also, given that this sounds like a real-time app, you only use printf for transferring a log, correct? Since printf and UART aren't very suitable for real-time stuff.

Comment: @Lundin Terminal I/O on IAR IDE is stdin/out window, for which data is sent through debugger using JTAG/SWD pins (or whatever is equivalent in TI) when semihosting is enabled. To my understanding, it isn't implemented as normal UART, and will require extra work if redirection to normal UART is wanted (or at least it does on ARM version which is the only one I have used).

Comment: Hmm ok that uses cycle stealing etc so it is a different beast indeed. That being said, setting up an UART to spit out some characters on a terminal isn't rocket science. Check app notes and drivers for the given MCU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can push all the data on UART which is used in communication between PCB and PC. Than you can use any serial monitor for getting data displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and opinions guys. Actually, these two solutions (UART and virtual COM port) I also consider as the only possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The only connection between your board and the PC is USB, so you have to implement a virtual USB COM port (CDC). TI's USB stack implements such an interface.

Comment: Ok, thank you, could you please make me sure how to proceed further? So my idea is to make a virtual COM port (using TI's USB developer's package) and after that use UART communication code (from MSP430 Interface to ADS1293 Code Library) for data transfer to the external Serial monitor. Is that right idea? If you have any other advice for me I will be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with "external serial monitor"? If it's the terminal you mentioned in your question, you have to access it through USB. The USB interface is *not* a hardware UART. See TI's USB examples.